# Can PHP easily parse JSON objects into PHP objects?

Tags: php, json

More or less, my question is as above.

I have A lot of data i am going to serialize and send to the server.  With that said, is there a PHP function to parse it into PHP-objects to manipulate on the Serverside?

My thought is yes due to the dynamic nature of PHP, but i wasnt sure what it would be.

Comment: -1 Sure it works. [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Did you even try it?

Comment: im writing up a proposal, and want to make sure PHP would be the langauge of choice for the project.

Comment: Is that somehow an excuse not to read the manual?

Comment: Just use something else. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html

Comment: you should ask your programmers what language they want to use.

Comment: If you're writing up something formal like a project proposal you might want to avoid using the term "JSON objects" since [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Radu I like your blog you posted.   Tbh, as a programmer and using it with different projects, i can easily see it all as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially answered your own question. From [the PHP manual entry for json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> **json_decode**
>
> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

That said, you'll obviously want to do all the requisite error checking and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `json_decode` with the true parameter to effectively convert it into to a PHP array like so: `$var = json_decode($object,true);`